# restart python script on raspberry if there are error or interruption of execution

Tags: linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

Hello everyone I work on a project where I have a raspberry with a Python script that must constantly work but it happens that there are errors and that the script stops with errors and therefore.

this Python script is connected 24 hours a day on the internet and uses a serial communication with electronics and so it happens that there are errors and that it stops the Python script

I am looking for a solution to restart automatically the python file as soon as there is an error or the script stops! maybe another script python checking this script or maybe reboot the systeme .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at the following [link](https://www.alexkras.com/how-to-restart-python-script-after-exception-and-run-it-forever/):

The gist is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
while True:
    print("\nStarting " + filename)
    p = Popen("python " + filename, shell=True)
    p.wait()
```